# How to start and stop a CSS animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I'm having a really hard time figuring out how to start and stop an animation and reverse it.

I've assigned an animation to the `element.style.animation` property and from what I've read, I decided to use:

```
element.style.animationPlayState = "running";
```

to start it and:

```
element.style.animationPlayState = "paused";
```

to stop it.

But it reports "running" all the time.

Has anyone figured out how to start and stop an animation?

I have a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58597057/8620333). The related part is this block of code that I use to make animations start and stop:

```
var style = element.style;
var animation = null;
style.animationPlayState = "paused";

if (style.animation) {
    animation = style.animation;
    style.animation = null;
    style.animationPlayState = "paused";
    element.addEventListener("animationend", function(event) {
        log("animation ended");
        element.removeEventListener("animationend", arguments.callee);
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
        style.animation = animation;
        style.animationPlayState = "paused";
        style.animationDirection = "reverse";
        style.animationPlayState = "running";
    }, 30);
}
```

The goal is simple:

- Display a `div` when user presses button
- `div` display is none, so set it to `display: block`
- Fade in `div`
- LATER - user presses a close button on `div`
- Fade out `div`
- After fade out set `display: none`

A method to do something like this:

```
fadeInElement(element)
fadeOutElement(element)
```

Comment: That link doesn't go to what you think it does.

Comment: you are always having `style.animationPlayState = "running";` at the last so it will always be running

Comment: Can we see a bit more code?

Comment: Can you drop the code sample?

Comment: Add Webkit to it aswell.

-webkit-animation-play-state: paused;                                                                                                                                              animation-play-state: paused;

I would love to see the code.

Comment: I've updated with some code

Comment: Wonder why you opened another question... Anyway - what is the goal? do you want that when the animation paused it will fade out until it disappears?

Comment: @A.Meshu I want to assign a fade in animation when the div appears and then I want NAY need to apply a fade out animation when the div disappears. I am choosing to reverse the fadein animation since it seemed the same amount of work.

Comment: `reverse` will not do what you think it will do, full explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57333022/8620333

Comment: You can't animate display: block and none. You can however animate opacity.

Comment: It sounds like reverse reverses the animation but doesn't reset it's position? I was able to reset everything by setting the animation property to null but it didn't apply right away in my tests. I had to set a timeout. I updated the question with more info. With two methods fadeIn and fadeOut that make it easier to solve.

Answer (score 1):

You can toggle classes with setTimeout, something like this maybe?

```js
var theDiv = document.querySelectorAll('div')[0];
function showDiv() {
  theDiv.setAttribute('class', 'fadeIn');
  setTimeout(function(){ theDiv.style.opacity = '1'; }, 2000);
}
function hideDiv() {
  theDiv.removeAttribute('class');  
  theDiv.setAttribute('class', 'fadeOut');
  setTimeout(function(){ theDiv.style.opacity = '0' }, 2000);
}
```

```css
div {height: 100px; height: 100px; background: black; opacity: 0;}
.fadeIn {animation: 2s fadein}
.fadeOut {animation: 2s fadeout}
@keyframes fadein {  to {opacity: 1;} }
@keyframes fadeout {  to {opacity: 0;} }
```

```html
<div></div>
<button onclick="showDiv()">Show DIV</button>
<button onclick="hideDiv()">Hide DIV</button>
```

EDIT

I changed the above code to something like this, though i guess you are looking for more modern solution:

```js
var theDiv = document.querySelectorAll('div')[0];
var anBtn = document.querySelector('#animateBtn');
var clicks = 1;
anBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  anBtn.disabled = true;
  if ((clicks/2) != (clicks/2).toFixed()) {
    showDiv();
  }
  else {
    hideDiv();
  }
  clicks += 1;
});
function showDiv() {
  theDiv.setAttribute('class', 'fadeIn');
  setTimeout(function(){ theDiv.style.opacity = '1'; anBtn.disabled = false; anBtn.textContent = 'Hide Div'; }, 2000);
}
function hideDiv() {
  theDiv.removeAttribute('class');
  theDiv.setAttribute('class', 'fadeOut');
  setTimeout(function(){ theDiv.style.opacity = '0'; anBtn.disabled = false; anBtn.textContent = 'Show Div'; }, 2000);
}
```

```css
div {height: 100px; height: 100px; background: black; opacity: 0;}
.fadeIn {animation: 2s fadein}
.fadeOut {animation: 2s fadeout}
@keyframes fadein {  to {opacity: 1;} }
@keyframes fadeout {  to {opacity: 0;} }
```

```html
<div></div>
<button id="animateBtn">Show DIV</button>
```

Comment: This sort of works. If you call hide too early it goes blank and then fades out.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts i update my answer though i guess you are looking for the new API solution...

Comment: I can't use the new solution yet. I appreciate the answer.

Answer (score 1):

With the Javascript Web Animations API you are able to use things like:

```
variable.play();
variable.pause();
```

it is a very powerful tool, here is the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API)

Also able to set the playback speed, including negative numbers which would play the animation in reverse. seems to address all of the issues that you brought up here.

Here is the polyfill which has proven to be very powerful, even works in IE

```
<script src="https://rawgit.com/web-animations/web-animations-js/master/web-animations.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for but native support is not ubiquitous yet. I may be able to use this in the future or with a polyfill.

Comment: There is definitely a polyfill, i'm putting the script tag into my answer

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to solve my own question with help provided. This sort of seems to work. But seems to break the edit window console.log. Also seems to break after a few runs. Maybe unrelated.

```js
var fadeInAnimation = "2s fadein";
var fadeOutAnimation = "2s fadein reverse";

function fadeIn() {
  var element = document.getElementById('box');
  //console.log("element", element);
  element.style.animation = fadeInAnimation;
  element.style.display = "block";
  //element.style.animationPlayState = "running";
}
function fadeOut() {
  var element = document.getElementById('box');
  element.style.display = "block";
  element.style.animationPlayState = "paused";
  element.style.animation = fadeOutAnimation;
  element.style.animationPlayState = "running";
  element.addEventListener("animationend", function(event) {
    element.style.display = "none";
console.log("animation ended");
    element.removeEventListener("animationend", arguments.callee);
  });
}
```

```css
#box {
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px; 
  background: red; 
  opacity: 1;
  display: none;
}

@keyframes fadein {  from {opacity: 0 } to {opacity: 1;} }
@keyframes fadeout {  from {opacity: 1 } to {opacity: 0;} }
```

```html
<button onclick="fadeIn()">Fade In</button>
<button onclick="fadeOut()">Fade Out</button>

<div id="box">
</div>
```